# stringstream errors c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand how `stringstream` works in order to be able to identify and convert possible numbers that were inputted as strings... for some reason this small piece of code I wrote to try and understand `stringstream` is being annoying with a few errors...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int str2int (const string &str) {
  std::stringstream ss(str);
  int num;
  if((ss >> num).fail())
  { 
      num = 0;
      return num;
  }
  return num;
}

int main(){
    int test;
    int t = 0;
    std::string input;
    while (t !=1){
        std::cout << "input: ";
        std::cin >> input;
        test = str2int(input);
        if(test == 0){
            std::cout << "Not a number...";
        }else
            std::cout << test << "\n";
        std::cin >> t;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
Error C2079:'ss' uses undefined class std::basic_stringstream<_elem,_traits,_alloc>'
Error C2228: left of '.fail' must have class/struct/union
Error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert 'const std::string' into 'int'
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not the reason behind the error messages, but one thing you're doing wrong is using `stringstream`, when you should be using `istringstream`.  (The use of `fail` is also not very idiomatic.)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to include the following header file -

```
#include <sstream>
```

Whenever you see errors like `undefined class`, you should always look for missing header files first.

[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/) is the documentation for the `stringstream` class.

Comment: They couldn't just call it stringstream.h

Answer (score 4):

You need to include sstream.

`#include <sstream>`

Answer (score 4):

I need to add - if your project uses **precompiled headers** (for example, `"stdafx.h"` for Win32 console app or `"pch.h"` for Windows Store app) - please check that they are included **ahead** of `<sstream>`.

Comment: This one worked for me, I tried to "organize" the includes and messed up this. Big Thankx Mr @Griever GF.

Answer (score 3):

Include this:

```
#include <sstream>
```

Also, write this:

```
if(ss >> num) //no .fail()
{ 
   return num; //read succeeded
}
return 0; //read failed
```

---

By the way, you could use `std::cin >> test` in the `main()` itself as:

```
int main(){
    int test;
    int t = 0;
    while (t !=1){
        std::cout << "input: ";
        if (std::cin >> test)
             std::cout << test << "\n";  //read succeeded
        else 
             std::cout << "Not a number...";  //read failed
        std::cin >> t;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

No need of `str2int` function!

Comment: Or simply `return ss >> num ? num : 0;`?  (Although I'd probably separate the `>>` out into a separate statement.  `ss >> num; return ss ? num : 0;`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: That's nice. :-)

Answer (score 3):

To use stringstream, you need to do;

```
#include <sstream>
```

After that, everything seems to work as it should.

Comment: smdh... I should go to bed lol. that kind of lack of attention is unacceptable... thanks.